# How can I execute a method in later class capable of combining lists from both classes?

Tags: python, python-3.x, class

Is it possible to combine the two lists by calling it from class B using the method I defined in the later class so that the results I may have are 1,2,3,4,5,6?

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.container = [1,2,3]

class B(A):
    def __init__(self):
        self.ano_containter = [4,5,6]

    def join_lists(self):
        for x in self.ano_containter:
            print(x)
```

Comment: If you correctly called the superclass initialiser I suppose you could do `for x in self.container + self.ano_containter:`. But it might be helpful to expand on what you're trying to achieve and precisely what the problem you're having is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not just concatenate them?

```
class B(A):
    def __init__(self):
        super(A, self).__init__()  # make sure you initialize your parent class properly
        self.ano_container = [4,5,6]

    def join_lists(self):
        return self.container + self.ano_container  # or print them if you wish
```

Comment: Thanks zwer for your answer. This is what I was looking for. It will take 10 minutes to accept your answer. Thanks again.

Comment: @SMth80 - there is a typo in the name `self.ano_containter` in the `__init__()` method - it should be `self.ano_container` (there is an extra `t`).